# How to run a scheduled task on a single openshift pod only?

Tags: java, kubernetes, openshift, scheduled-tasks

**Story**: in my java code i have a few ScheduledFuture's that i need to run everyday on specific time (15:00 for example), the only available thing that i have is database, my current application and openshift with multiple pods. I can't move this code out of my application and must run it from there.

**Problem**: ScheduledFuture works on every pod, but i need to run it only once a day. I have a few ideas, but i don't know how to implement them.

**Idea #1**:
Set environment variable to specific pod, then i will be able to check if this variable exists (and its value), read it and run schedule task if required. I know that i have a risk of hovered pods, but that's better not to run scheduled task at all than to run it multiple times.

**Idea #2**:
Determine a leader pod somehow, this seems to be a bad idea in my case since it always have "split-brain" problem.

**Idea #3 (a bit offtopic)**:
Create my own synchronization algorithm thru database. To be fair, it's the simplest way to me since i'm a programmer and not SRE. I understand that this is not the best one tho.

**Idea #4 (a bit offtopic)**:
Just use quartz schedule library. I personally don't really like that and would prefer one of the first two ideas (if i will able to implement them), but at the moment it seems like my only valid choice.

UPD. May be you have some other suggestions or a warning that i shouldn't ever do that?

Comment: I would suggest to use a ready-to-use solution. Getting those things right, especially covering all possible corner-cases wrt. reliability, is hard. If you do not want to use quartz, I would at least suggest to use a database-backed solution. Postgres, for example, has `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;` which may be used to implement one-time only scheduling.

Comment: @Turing85, that's exactly what i used after all. You can create an "answer" and i will choose it as the right one if you want. For me it was oracle, `FOR UPDATE NOWAIT`

Comment: [Done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67788091/4216641).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use a ready-to-use solution. Getting those things right, especially covering all possible corner-cases wrt. reliability, is hard. If you do not want to use quartz, I would at least suggest to use a database-backed solution. Postgres, for example, has [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;` (scroll down to the section "The Locking Clause")](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) which may be used to implement one-time only scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

You can create cron job using openshift
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/nodes/jobs/nodes-nodes-jobs.html
and have this job trigger some endpoint in you application that will invoke your logic.

Comment: I thought about this solution, but it seems very unclear to somebody new. With time it will be a forbidden knowledge :) I guess comment above this request can help it.